# How Do I Position This Script Within A Table?

Tags: javascript, php

I am pulling data from a google sheet that has pricing.  My goal is to have it within a div and display it over an image eventually.  The issue I am having right now is it keeps putting it top left of page.  How can I position this and also, I feel like this is not the proper way to do this.  Maybe somebody has a solution or point me in the right direction?

```
<html>
<body>
  <pre id='data'></pre>
  <pre id='data1'></pre>
</body>
<script>
  const onDataLoaded = (data) => {
    const e20Content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'A2').content.$t
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = e20Content
  }
</script>

<script>
  const onDataLoaded1 = (data1) => {
    const e20Content = data1.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'B2').content.$t
    document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML = e20Content1
  }
</script>




<table>
<tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Model</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1UXGv7fA_B5GI2iyWrbBuXOaSqjIW2YHJLYnxq7dcbFc/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded1"></script><pre id='data'></pre></td>
    <td><script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1UXGv7fA_B5GI2iyWrbBuXOaSqjIW2YHJLYnxq7dcbFc/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded"></script><pre id='data1'></pre></td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: you should really just have your js in one file and call that ..

Comment: @treyBake Yeah I am just testing at the moment to see if I can get this to work.  I will separate it all out when I am finalizing the scripts.

Comment: But what's the point? Your JS should not be in a table..